# How can I acces the N'th object property name?

Tags: php, arrays, object, type-conversion

I have an object containing an unknown number of properties, is there any way to get the N'th property name of this object in PHP?

I'm expecting it to be something similar to the following code, except that this will only work with an array, not objects:

```
$key = array_keys($obj)[$i];
```

Assuming the following input:

```
$obj = stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [name] => Mary Jane
            [count] => 420
        )
$i = 1;
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
ID
```

Comment: $obj isn't an array, so why did you expect an array function to work on it like that? Objects aren't arrays, and don't have keys, they have properties

Comment: Yes Im aware this code doesn't work, I'm asking if there is an equivalent

Comment: Cast the object to an array `$obj = (array) $obj;`

Comment: $key = array_search($i, (array)$obj);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast your object to an array first:

```
$key = array_keys((array)$obj)[$i];
```

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

You can use
 `get_object_vars()`

Comment: Thank you for you input but I tried both methods suggested and casting the object seems to be the more practical way to solve my particular problem. Using this function mean that I needed to also nest the array_keys function anyway like: `array_keys(get_object_vars($a))[$i];`

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it with foreach:

```
foreach ($obj as $attr)
{
   var_dump($attr);
}
```

It works but you'll need a counter to decrement according to the number of iteration then break.

Edit: get_object_vars is better, sry.